# Проблема с уведомлением об изменении вопроса

Tags: дефект, вопросы, правки

Есть у меня [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1011784/%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%83-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8E-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BF-%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BC%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B8-android). Который обсуждался в комментариях. Но сейчас возникла довольно интересная ситуация - он отредактирован [участником](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/312975/%D0%92%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%92%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%BE%D0%B2). Я как бы не против, если человек может его улучшить, то это хорошо. Но проблема в том что уведомление об изменении висит на главной странице:

> [image: Список вопросов]

а при просмотре вопроса ничего нет:

> [image: Страница самого вопроса]

Возможно участник отдал свой голос на закрытие вопроса (хотя репы не очень много для этого)? Или всё нормально и я придираюсь к мелочам :)

Comment: Что интересно, даже в [таймлайне](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1011784/timeline) ты не увидишь что реально произошло, если репутации недостаточно...

Comment: @АндрейNOP ага, я именно поэтому на MSE вопрос задавал)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Я похожий вопрос на MSE задавал: [Show last modification date only for changes that can be viewed by the user](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/323820/260198).

Это не связано с редактирование вопроса, голосами и т.п.

Суть в том, что человек дал ответ на вопрос, но потом удалил его. На странице со списком вопросов это и показывается. Но удалённого ответа вы не видите, так как репутации не достаточно.

> [image: Удалённый ответ.]

Comment: а оно уберется через время или так и будет висеть?

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko если больше никаких действий с вопросом не будет, то так и останется.

Comment: но это же не очень хорошо,  я правильно понимаю?

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko возможно, но исправлять это не будут точно)

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko, если ты имел в виду, исчезнет ли вопрос с главной - то да, если других изменений не будет, то дата изменения меняться не будет и со временем он оттуда уползёт.

Comment: @Qwertiy, я имел в виду останется ли текущий статус измененного вопроса :)

Comment: _"так как репутации не достаточно."_ А с какого количества репутации можно будет увидеть удалённые ответы других участников? Так же, как и для вопросов, — с 10К?

Comment: @nomnoms12 с [10k](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools).